# Creating unordered map of class objects

Tags: c++, class, object, unordered-map

I have created a function that is supposed to read in information from a .txt file, store it in a class object which is then stored in a hash table. I have tested the reading of the information and it works fine. The problems arise when either I try to store the information in the object or storing the object in the hash table. The code for the function is shown below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include <sstream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "car.h"
using namespace std;



unordered_map <string, car> allCars;

void readInput()
{

    int arr[24];
    int x = 0;
    int numberofCases,milemarker;
    string line,datetime,enterexit,license;


    ifstream File;
    File.open("input.txt");
    File >> numberofCases;


    while (x <= numberofCases)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            File >> arr[i];

        }

        getline(File, line);
        while (getline(File, line))
        {
            if (line.empty())
            {
                x++;
                for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
                {
                    File >> arr[i];
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
                {
                    cout << arr[i] << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
                getline(File, line);
                getline(File, line);
                stringstream lineStream(line);
                lineStream >> license >> datetime >> enterexit >> milemarker;
                string sub = datetime.substr(6, 2);
                int hour = stoi(sub);
                if (allCars.count(license))
                    {
                        (allCars[license]).settollCost(arr[hour]);
                        if (enterexit == "enter")
                        {
                            (allCars[license]).setcarEnter(milemarker);
                        }           
                        else if (enterexit == "exit")
                        {
                            (allCars[license]).setcarExit(milemarker);
                            (allCars[license]).calculateMiles;
                            (allCars[license]).calculateBill; // calculates bill for trip
                            (allCars[license]).printInfo;
                        }

                    }
                else if (!allCars.count(license))
                {
                    car car1(license);
                    allCars[license] = car1;
                }
                cout << license << endl << datetime << endl << enterexit << endl << milemarker << endl << hour << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                stringstream lineStream(line);
                lineStream >> license >> datetime >> enterexit >> milemarker;
                string sub = datetime.substr(6, 2);
                int hour = stoi(sub);
                if (allCars.count(license))
                {
                    (allCars[license]).settollCost(arr[hour]);
                    if (enterexit == "enter")
                    {
                        (allCars[license]).setcarEnter(milemarker);
                    }
                    else if (enterexit == "exit")
                    {
                        (allCars[license]).setcarExit(milemarker);
                        (allCars[license]).calculateMiles;
                        (allCars[license]).calculateBill; // calculates bill for trip
                        (allCars[license]).printInfo;
                    }

                }
                else if (!allCars.count(license))
                {
                    car car1(license);
                    allCars[license] = car1;
                }
                cout << license << endl << datetime << endl << enterexit << endl << milemarker << endl << hour << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
                {
                    cout << arr[i] << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
            }
    }

}
```

The output I get from the build is as follows:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\tuple(746): error C2512: 'car' : no appropriate default constructor available
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\tuple(762) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair<std::tuple<const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &>,std::tuple<>,0,>(_Tuple1 &,_Tuple2 &,std::_Arg_idx<0>,std::_Arg_idx<>)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=car
1>  ,            _Tuple1=std::tuple<const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &>
1>  ,            _Tuple2=std::tuple<>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\tuple(762) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair<std::tuple<const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &>,std::tuple<>,0,>(_Tuple1 &,_Tuple2 &,std::_Arg_idx<0>,std::_Arg_idx<>)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=car
1>  ,            _Tuple1=std::tuple<const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &>
1>  ,            _Tuple2=std::tuple<>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(600) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair<const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>&,>(std::piecewise_construct_t,std::tuple<const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &>,std::tuple<>)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=car
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(600) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair<const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>&,>(std::piecewise_construct_t,std::tuple<const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &>,std::tuple<>)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=car
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(723) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Other>::construct<_Objty,const std::piecewise_construct_t&,_Ty,std::tuple<>>(_Objty *,const std::piecewise_construct_t &,_Ty &&,std::tuple<> &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Other=std::_List_node<std::pair<const std::string,car>,void *>
1>  ,            _Objty=std::pair<const std::string,car>
1>  ,            _Ty=std::tuple<const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &>
1>          ]
```

The whole output is actually longer, but almost all of them are along the same lines as posted above. I have no idea what any of that means or what exactly I did wrong so any clarifications would be appreciated. If you need anymore information such as the class definition or header file, I can provide that; just didn't want to overload the question.

Comment: You will need to provide the source for `car.h` so people can tell you that you don't have a default constructor.

Comment: Derp, sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nemo said, you most likely don't have a default constructor for your `car` class, [which the `operator[]` of unordered_map requires](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator[]/).

You either need to make a default constructor, or use `insert` and `find` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response, totally forgot about it.